# Is the nftw(file tree walk) function available on Windows

Tags: c, linux, windows

I'm writing code to walk a directory and its subdirs on linux using `nftw`. Is the `nftw`function available on Windows?

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx) contains references of all of the Windows APIs. If nothing else, your favorite search engine might help you too.

Comment: I have searched but have found nothing definitive.

Answer (score 0):

Not as part of the standard Windows APIs, no.

Also note that [the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/nftw) claims:

> Conforming To
>   POSIX.1-2001, SVr4, SUSv1. POSIX.1-2008 marks ftw() as obsolete.

So it's perhaps not the best starting point even when targetting POSIX.

Still, [this library](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libgw32c.htm) implements it for Windows.

Comment: `ftw` is obsolete but not `nftw` !