# return files in vector from directory and subdirectories with c++

Tags: c++

I want to make a method that read all files in directory and subdirectories of it and return a vector with the names of the files. So far I can't find something useful about that problem :/
here is an example of my method wchich is read the files in directory but not in subdrictories

```
vector open_directories(const string path_dir)
{
    DIR *directory;
    dirent *pdir;
    vector<string> files_name;

    dir = opendir(path_dir.c_str());

    while((pdir = reddir(dir))) {
        files_name.push_back(pdir->d_name);
    }

    return files_name;
}
```

there is any solution to open subdirectories also ?

Comment: Opening the sub-directory is the same as opening the directory. If you want also files from sub-sub-directories, then use your function recursively and combine the results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently Traverse Directory Tree with opendir(), readdir() and closedir()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312110/efficiently-traverse-directory-tree-with-opendir-readdir-and-closedir)

Comment: Use [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html) and save yourself the trouble,

Comment: If your program needs to run in Windows please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225813/is-the-nftwfile-tree-walk-function-available-on-windows

Comment: Why dont you use the logic `files_name.push_back(pdir->d_name);`  in a dedicated function which you call recursively till the time you dont get anything? This will take you to the bottommost part of your tree; samewyas do it for other directories too. Let me know if it is still unclear.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the `<filesystem>` header available on your environment, then you can use [std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/recursive_directory_iterator) for this
i.e.

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> getFilenamesRecursive(const std::string& directory) {
  std::vector<std::string> retVal;
  std::tr2::sys::path path(directory);
  for (auto it = std::tr2::sys::recursive_directory_iterator(path);
  it != std::tr2::sys::recursive_directory_iterator(); ++it) {
    retVal.push_back(it->path().generic_string());
  }
  return retVal;
}
```